# how to prevent over writing file while 'composer update' command

Tags: composer-php, laravel-5.1

I am working on laravel 5.1 project. I have updated few files for customization e.g. vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php file. It needed to install new package so I had modified composer.json and run command 'composer update' and package was installed but all the code I had updated in AuthenticatesUsers.php file was replaced with original.

How to prevent this over-writing while updating composer?

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to edit files in the vendor folder if you also want to use Composer to easily update your dependencies. Editing files of external packages effectively means you are forking that project and maintain it yourself. This either means you only apply your change once and then stop all further development, or you constantly have to check for updates of the original package and merge their changes with your changes.

I am pretty sure there are ways to solve the underlying problem with adding changes to existing files, but your current question suffers from the [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) - you want to add a change to Laravel but don't know how to do properly, find that editing may solve the problem, but now need to prevent overwriting that file, and ask about preventing that overwriting - instead of asking how to add change to Laravel classes.

Comment: May be you are right. Actually have started started with laravel not so long ago. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Consider packages like [mpdf](https://packagist.org/packages/mpdf/mpdf) which actually **require** you to add files and edit config files to work. I know I'm not supposed to edit vendor files, but to use the package I **need** to add files and edit vendor files, this is not a choice.

Comment: I probably shouldn't comment on software like "mpdf" that disqualifies itself by not being updated to accomodate modern PHP (this software is still PHP 4!). Don't use it! It's configuration mechanism is not compatible with the modern way of using Composer. But you could still define _MPDF_PATH to override the package provided configuration (and live with the pain this induces), or start investigation how to configure that package in an alternative way. Sadly, I know of no PDF library that isn't broken in this way, because all I've seen inherit from fpdf. Best so far: TCPDF.

Answer (score 0):

A nice and clean solution would be to [fork the repository](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/) and add it to [packagist](https://packagist.org/). Then simply change the composer dependency with your version of improved (so to speak) laravel's source code.

Comment: I will look into this, Thanks.

Comment: That probably isn't nice and clean, because the solution contains forking a project. This instantly doubles the amount of maintenance work and increases the risk of incompatible development.

Comment: It is the only option if you want to edit the source code. Or probably you have something on your mind? :)

Comment: You don't have to put it on packagist or others, you can use a private repository as well. See this https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#using-private-repositories